# How to dynamically pull MYSQL date queries?

Tags: mysql, date, dynamic

I am trying to select data from two periods (Last 30 days and Previous 30 days)
So two 30 day periods.

I have the last 30 day period down:

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductIDintarget,date_format(Date,'%m/%d/%Y'),SUM(Rev)
FROM datatable
WHERE Date BETWEEN CURDATE()-1 - INTERVAL 31 DAY AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY ProductIDintarget
```

That is working fine, but now I'm struggling to get the previous 30 day period.

I have tried changing the WHERE statement as:

```
WHERE Date BETWEEN CURDATE()-32 - INTERVAL 31 DAY AND CURDATE()-32
```

but no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DATE_ADD()` or `DATE_SUB()` like this:

```
SELECT 
  ProductID, 
  ProductIDintarget,
  DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%m/%d/%Y'),
  SUM(Rev)
FROM datatable
WHERE `Date` < (DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
AND `Date` > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
GROUP BY 
  ProductID, 
  ProductIDintarget,
  `Date`
```

*Note:- You should backticks if you have keywords as column names.*

Comment: Awesome. Only thing wrong in your answer is the WHERE.. I fixed it by setting: WHERE `Date` > (DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -60 day)), since I want it to start 60 days from now. Is my understanding correct?